# Randomly Generating Enemies Android

Tags: java, android, sprite

I am making a game in android in which enemies are randomly spawned at the top of the screen and move down.  I am able to create 1 enemy that does this, but I can't think of a good way to create many enemies that are all drawn on the same canvas.  I have tried many things, and I could really use some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code and I would be happy to help :)

Comment: Place your code that generates 1 enemy into a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a class `Enemy` (name it whatever you like) and instantiate as many as you need using a `for` loop. You could use an `array` to store each instance.

An example could be the following:

```
Enemy[] arrayOfEnemies = new Enemy[sizeOfArray];
for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfEnemies.length; i++) {
    arrayOfEnemies[i] = new Enemy();    

}
```

Then you can use an enhanced for (or for each) loop to display them wherever you'd like on your canvas.

Comment: correct , though i would prefer a collection (like ArrayList) .

Comment: And there are chances that you will have to implement your game logic in a separate thread to prevent blocking the UI thread. And you will draw in the UI thread. Thus, you will need to synchroonize accesses to the List implementation. Therefore, choosing a vector might ease things, or do it by hand and synchronize on the list whenever you add or remove ennemies, and when using an iterator to paint your ennemies on screen.